# WordPress Multi Site Best Practice

Tags: customization, multisite

This question is mainly to get some clarification on best practice for setting up a WordPress Multi-Site.  As I have not done this before.  I have outlined the scenario below.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Two Sites with very similar front-ends and an almost identical press section that is managed by WordPress.

Site One : US Version of the site built in WordPress templates files. Press section managed from WordPress.

Site Two: UK Version of the site, some pages eliminated and a portion of the press from the US site will be the same on the UK site.

I see this being the correct application for WordPress Multisite.  I see this running with 2 domains (site.com, site.co.uk) and running all the press clips off of one DB in Multisite with denoting a checkbox or category to apply the US clips to the UK site.

I would like to know what would be the best approach for this and if the overall consensus is that this is the proper fit for WP Multi Site.

Thank you in advance!

JN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multisite does not have cross-posting built in. you can do what you want with one of these:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/

Answer (score 0):

When you have a hosting company that doesn't support dynamic subdomains, there is a [workaround](http://keithjameslock.com/wordpress-mu-with-subdomains-godaddy-shared-hosting/).  Just create the subdomain with your hosting pointing towards the main folder of your primary WP blog and WP takes care of the redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation that I'm working on with re: to WordPress, Multisite and both a US & UK versions.  The wildcard, in my case, is that several key players in the project feel that it would be better to host the UK site in the UK and the US site here in the US....for SEO reasons.  I did some reading up and it seems that this might be a good idea....other than that I'll need to find a way to syndicate/re-post some of the UK blog entries over to the US site.  Anyway...has I didn't really provide you with an answer...but I'm right there with you...trying to determine if a Multisite install made sense or not.

Have you considered splitting the sites up geographically?